# Shell: How to iterate over directories names and get two latest?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Lets say I have the following directories names on aws s3 bucket. This output is returned by `aws s3 ls`:

```
PRE 20161205_1248/
PRE 20161207_1613/
PRE 20161211_1732/
PRE 20161213_1806/
PRE 20161216_0603/
PRE 20161219_0255/
PRE 20161224_1350/
PRE 20161226_1915/
PRE 20161229_0154/
PRE 20161231_1139/
```

Where directory names are timestamps and the latest is:

```
20161205_1248
```

How can I iterate over directories names to get the one before latest? I`m new to shell scripting so will be grateful for any help

Comment: Isn't `20161205_1248` the oldest, where `20161231_1139` being the latest? What is your actual output.

Answer (score 0):

1. List all files in the directory with ls
2. Sort them recursively with sort
3. Get the last 2 lines with tail
4. Get the 1st line of this fraction with head

   ```
   ls | sort -r | tail -2 | head -1
   ```

If you confused lastest with last, then leave the -r option away from sort.

Comment: Alternatively, use `sed` to print a specific line, a la `ls | sort -r | sed -n '2{p;q}'`

Comment: Yes, your command is even shorter. But leaving away the semicolon after the q command gave me an error message (on a mac). Do you need q or would `sed -n '2p'` do it anyway?

Comment: I suppose strictly speaking, the `q` is not necessary - it just exits early and avoids reading the rest of the file/input. In this case, since the input is so small, it probably doesn't matter, but in cases where you're fetching one specific line out of 3 billion or something, it can make a noticeable difference.

Comment: Thanks! After some research Ive found that aws ls actually returns listing as a string, like PRE DIR1/ PRE DIR2/ PRE DIR3/ but as far as I need to get only 'DIR3' ive managed to get it like `function test {
 dir=$(aws s3 ls s3://dir_location/ | sort -r)    
 read -a arr <<<$dir
 echo ${arr[3]} | sed s'/.$//'
}`